# AngularJS - Filter array by using nested objects in check boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to filter an array by using nested objects, it means filter the array by using multiple check boxes but I have an issue with the duplicate names.
This is the [source code](https://jsfiddle.net/wefs/rqwoxvzt/) I've been trying to use.

Any idea about how to fix the duplicate names issue?

**html**

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
<div data-ng-controller="controller">

<strong>Pick a brand to see the models</strong>
<div ng-init="group = (cars | groupBy:'make')">
    <div ng-repeat="m in group">
        <b><input type="checkbox" checked="true" ng-model="useMakes[$index]"/>{{m.name}}</b>
    </div>
</div>

<br/>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Name</th>
    <th>Maker</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:filterMakes()">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{car.make.name}}</td>
    <td>{{car.model}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("controller", function($scope){
    $scope.useMakes = [];

    $scope.filterMakes = function () {
        return function (p) {
        for (var i in $scope.useMakes) {
             if (p.make == $scope.group[i] && $scope.useMakes[i]) {
             return true;
             }
        }
    };
 };

 $scope.makes = [
     {id:1, name: "BMV"},
     {id:2, name: "Ford"},
     {id:3, name: "Renault"},
     {id:4, name: "Seat"},
     {id:5, name: "Opel"}
 ];

 $scope.cars = [
     {model: '316', make: {id: 1, name: "BMV"}},
     {model: '520', make: {id: 1, name: "BMV"}},
     {model: 'Fiesta', make: {id: 2, name: "Ford"}},
     {model: 'Focus', make: {id: 2, name: "Ford"}},
     {model: 'Clio', make: {id: 3, name: "Renault"}},
     {model: 'Toledo', make: {id: 4, name: "Seat"}},
     {model: 'Leon', make: {id: 4, name: "Seat"}},
     {model: 'Insignia', make: {id: 5, name: "Opel"}},
     {model: 'Astra', make: {id: 5, name: "Opel"}},
     {model: 'Corsa', make: {id: 5, name: "Opel"}}
 ];

 });

 /*I think here is the problem*/
 var uniqueItems = function (data, key) {
     var result = new Array();
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     var value = data[i][key];

    if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        result.push(value);
    }

 }
 return result;
 };

 myApp.filter('groupBy', function () {
     return function (collection, key) {
     if (collection === null) return;
     return uniqueItems(collection, key);
     };
});
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi, can you give me a hand with this little issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle or a Codepen, so we can play with the code to help you out more?

Comment: @BrianLogan Sure, here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/wefs/rqwoxvzt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of problem is that when using `indexOf` in the `uniqueItems()`, the object reference (a.k.a memory address) is being used for comparison to check whether something is already in the array.

The effor to uniqify won't work as expected because the `$scope.cars[0].make` and `$scope.cars[1].make` are declared at 2 different places and hence will be created as 2 diffferent object references.

There are two possible solutions:

**Alternative Solution #1 (preferred)**: make every `make` in the `$scope.cars` to refer to objects that are already declared in the `$scope.makes`. This is the preferred solution because you will have one central place that specifies what the make names are ([Single Source Of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)), i.e. you only need to change one place if later you want to fix the "BMV" to "BMW".

```
$scope.cars = [
  {model: '316', make: $scope.makes[0]},
  {model: '520', make: $scope.makes[0]},
  {model: 'Fiesta', make: $scope.makes[1]},
  {model: 'Focus', make: $scope.makes[1]},
  {model: 'Clio', make: $scope.makes[2]},
  {model: 'Toledo', make: $scope.makes[2]},
  {model: 'Leon', make: $scope.makes[3]},
  {model: 'Insignia', make: $scope.makes[4]},
  {model: 'Astra', make: $scope.makes[4]},
  {model: 'Corsa', make: $scope.makes[4]}
];
```

**Alternative Solution #2**: if you want to keep the `$scope.cars` for some reasons, we need to fix the `$scope.filterMakes()` and `uniqueItems()` to only compare the unique attribute of `make` instead of the `make` object reference. In this case, we can compare the `make.id`.

```
$scope.filterMakes = function () {
    return function (p) {
        for (var i in $scope.useMakes) {
            if (p.make.id == $scope.group[i].id && $scope.useMakes[i]) {  //add the ".id"
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
};

var uniqueItems = function (data, key) {
    var result = new Array();
    var added = []; //same as new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i][key];
        if (added.indexOf(value.id) == -1) { //look for the id
            result.push(value);
            added.push(value.id); //list of added ids
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll choose the #2 solution.

Comment: Hi, I have a little issue based in your answer, please see the readme file from this example http://plnkr.co/edit/W9OKntBW7sIsm5xDUbOJ?p=preview in order to get a more detailed explanation. I'll really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, the json loading is an async process, so we need to run your ng-init code right after `$scope.cars` has been loaded because `$scope.group` depends on it. Additionally, in the groupBy we need to handle when `collection` is undefined. I have slightly modified your code, see http://plnkr.co/edit/VTdfVw1sNKUU2jpYBQQ9

Comment: Sorry man, it's me again. I have been trying to understand how to set all checkboxes selected by default. Any idea?  Thanks.

Comment: initialize your `$scope.useMakes`. Add this `for (var i=0; i< $scope.group.length; i++) $scope.useMakes[i] = true;` just right after you initialize the `$scope.group`. I have updated my plunkr above.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'unique' filter

```
   <div ng-repeat="m in group | unique:'name'">
            <b><input type="checkbox" checked="true" ng-model="useMakes[$index]"/>{{m.name}}</b>
   </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/7g78b5p7/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **unique** filter from AngularUI (source code available here: [AngularUI unique filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)) and use it directly in the ng-options (or ng-repeat).

```
<select ng-model="orderProp" ng-options="place.category for place in places | unique:'category'">
    <option value="0">Default</option>
    // unique options from the categories
</select>
```